# Facebook like button not displaying inside WordPress posts loop

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

The facebook like button is not displaying when I try to insert it inside the WordPress single post template `content-single.php`. Actually the facebook like button markup is loading in the webpage source code, but for some reason the button is not displaying. If I put the button code before or after the post loop all is fine. Any idea how I can get the like button inside the `content-single.php` template to display if possible, not using jQuery?

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-width="200" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

The above should be called from inside the `content-single.php` template:

```
<div id="content">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>      
      <?php comments_template( '/article-comments.php' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Edit:

the basic content of the `content-single.php` is:

```
<div class="featuredImage" style="clear:both;float:left;">
   <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
      the_post_thumbnail('thumb-400');
    } 
  ?>
</div>
<div class="caption">
   <?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?>
 </div>

<div class="single-entry-content" style="width:70%;float:left">
  <p class="summary"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'entry', true);?></p>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:',     'yoko' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>                   
  <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit &rarr;', 'yoko' ), '| <span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</div>
```

Inside this file is also a related articles sidebar with multiple calls to the `wp_get_object_terms` function.

Comment: Would you mind including more content from inside the content-single?

Comment: This is sounding more like a CSS issue. It probably has to do with the container that the fb-like is in.